# Enabling multipath in ns2 with no rtproto DV

Tags: routing

So I am trying to run a simulation using the MPTCP protocol in a data center but rtProto DV is not working; produces an error, I am guessing the implementations doesn't have support for it and I can't figure out what to change so it works. For anyone interested that might have an idea this is the error I get and how I might fix it or where to look

```
ns: _o344 recv-update 0 0: can't read "class::": no such variable
    while executing
"error "$class::$proc update $peerAddr:$msg:$count from unknown peer""
    (procedure "_o344" line 36)
    (Agent/rtProto/DV recv-update line 36)
    invoked from within
"_o344 recv-update 0 0"
```

So now I am trying to make it so the simulation uses all paths. I am using a k-tree.

[image]

I was thinking of maybe using add-routes and enabling multiPath_ that it might work but the problem is I am not sure how to use add-routes in my case.
The topology is k-tree with the k=4 so basically I want to add the additional choices in the pods and core level. How would I go about it? Would I for every node inside each pod add for every possible server all the following nodes that are possible?
For example in the image from source to destination in the first round node it encounters;
would I do a for-loop on that node and for every host (black square nodes) I would add as next hop both round nodes on the upper level of the pod and enable multiPath_? and so on for all the nodes?

Anyone has any other idea of how I would solve this, or maybe even what to look into changing so DV works?

Comment: I have met the same problem about the multipath routing in ns2.34. In the ns manual ,it said that "currently, only DV routing can generate multipath routes". Also through the simulation, I find that DV can work in a simple topology, but can't in the FatTree. Have you solved it?

Comment: Yeah, I used the LS routing for mptcp. also, for mptcp you should create all the pairs of tcp endpoint before you start the simulation. LS for link state. I think it's mentioned in the manual 3 times (NOT in the routing chapters) and is mentioned in the start that it won't be discussed.